# Will my geographical positions be tracked and stored in the google location history when my internet connection is temporarily interrupted?

Tags: google-location-history

I'm about to travel to a region where I will not have Internet connection.
I'm going to activate the location services during this time.(switch GPS on and allow position tracking). Will my GPS positions be recorded and my Google location history updated as soon as I reconnect to the Internet, or do I need a location Logger app?
If I need a separate app, is it possible to add the recorded tracks to the Google location history later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after my vacation I know for certain that it is possible to record the positions without an open internet connection.
As soon as an app requests a position (in my case an offline map app)  this position will be stored (cached) by the location services from google.
The positions will be transferred to google as soon as an connection has been established.
I have no details about the number of positions that will be handled this way.